# Lifecycle methods executed on Fragment object creation

Tags: android, android-fragments

What `Fragment` life cycle methods get executed when a fragment object is **only created** inside the activity before being displayed using Fragment Transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you create a object of the **Fragment** it is just like creating a object of a normal class. There is noting special in creating object for **Fragment**.

Once attached to the Fragment Manager and when you begin transition. Then only it is attached to the **Activity** and `onAttach(Activity)` called once the fragment is associated with its activity.

After that the remaining life cycle methods will be called.

`onDetach()` called immediately prior to the fragment no longer being associated with its activity.

For more info look at this link.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 1):

`None of them`, because it only allocates memory for `Fragment` object when created but it starts invoking lifecycle `methods` while rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing what rajan ks said, that is why you are not intended to use custom constructors on fragments. Instead, you're supposed to pass parameters using static methods (as *newInstance*). So, when the fragment renders, it can obtain the parameters in the "onCreate" method.

If you see the lifecycle diagram [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?#Creating), all the stuff starts when the **fragment is added**

Comment: Could you tell more about why we should use static methods like newInstance rather than constructors? @Brian